# PHP Regexp - if custom punctuation symbols are side-by-side, then regex doesn't match

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, numbers, punctuation

### my regexp

**`/^[\p{L}\p{N}][\p{L}\p{N} \.,;:\?!-“”‘’"']+$/u`**

### aim of regexp

allow `utf-8` characters, numbers, spaces AND custom punctuation to verify article title

these inputs below don't match but I want matching also if punctuation are side-by side? Can you show me the correct form of my regexp? note: Backslash in front of dot and question mark are for escaping attempt. I also tried without escaping. I am not good at regexp. I can only find sub-parts then try to combine. thanks. BR

### inputs that don't match

1. "Selim"!'"':?-
2. "'
3. '"
4. ?!
5. I also discovered that I can not start with punctuation to a title.
   example **"title" Day** doesn't match

Comment: escape the - also: \-

Comment: didn't work unfortunately. I know that dash (-) is NOT a special character who needs to be escaped.

Comment: /^\w*$/u  should match all utf-8 characters

Comment: /^\w*$/u doens't match title day on rubular.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change with:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{N}“”‘’"'][\p{L}\p{N} .,;:?!\-“”‘’"']*$/u
```

NB: `-` must be escaped if it isn't in the first or last position within the character class. But `.` and `?` doesn't need.

Answer (score 1):

Are the square brackets within the regex characters you accept?  If so, they need to be escaped.

```
/^[\p{L}\p{N}\]\[\p{L}\p{N} \.,;:\?!-“”‘’"']+$/u
```

If not, then you need to include the punctuation you'll allow inside the first character class.

Comment: Yes I escaped before ' character as \' since my code is if (!preg_match('/^[\p{L}\p{N}“”‘’"\'][\p{L}\p{N} .,;:?!\-“”‘’"\']*$/u',$str)). Thanks for your warning also.